# Can't connect to JHipster UAA server using Curl

Tags: docker, oauth, docker-compose, token, jhipster

I am running a docker-compose'd architecture with a registry, gateway (8080), uaa (9999), and 2 microservices (8081 and 8082) and I can see the Swagger API in the gateway app via dropdown selection. I can login to the gateway with admin and user. I've also modified to the code to accept an owner, agent, and monitor role. I can login just fine.

In a terminal I tried Baeldung's curl command (Blog posting) to get a token from the uaa server directly for testing APIs.

```sh
[~]$ curl -X POST --data  "username=user&password=user&grant_type=password&scope=openid"  http://localhost:9999/oauth/token
    curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9999: Connection refused
```

I opened Kitematic and the uaa server is localhost (host) and 9999 (port) in the docker container log.

Can someone help me figure out why Curl is not working for me?

thanks,

David

Comment: Are you issueing the curl command from the host machine? And, can you post the docker-compose definition in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is almost certainly related to the network properties of the stack that you are deploying.

If you are issuing the curl command from the host machine to http://localhost:9999, then you need to make sure that the UAA server is mapping it's port to the host.

Does your UAA service have this in the `docker-compose.yml`?

```
    ports:
      - "9999:9999"
```

If not, you need to add it in order to test it from the host.

By default, docker-compose will create a bridge network for your stack, where your containers can talk to eachother and resolve eachother on container names. But from the host, you will not be able to address the containers unless you explicitly map their exposed ports to the ports on the host.

Comment: I had to add ... the ports: "9999:9999" to gain access the localhost:9999 in the Docker container. Now my curl call above is giving me a HTTP 401 - Unauthorized. I need to find the right cURL call for my OAuth (uaa) server. I want to be able to test my new APIs outside of the Gateway app and writing Angular code. I want to write Javascript npm request calls (async) to test the APIs. I'll give you a +1 vote because the double port mapping being missing was why the app could login and I couldn't see localhost inside the container. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @DavidWhitehurst! Did you resolve the issue? What did you have to add?

Comment: See up. New problem, my call for the token is probably wrong.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer - I hope you resolve the authentication issue with the UAA server!